# Email Content creation | Proper design

Tags: java, design, design-patterns

Working on an E commerce application where we need to send so many email to customer like

- Registration email
- Forget Password
- Order placed

There are many other emails that can be sent, I already have `emailService` in place which is responsible for sending email and It needs an Email object, Everything is working find, but I am struck at one point and not sure how best this can be done.

We need to create content so as it can be passed to `emailService` and not sure how to design this.

For example, in Customer registration, I have a `customerFacade` which is working between `Controller` and `ServiceLayer`, I just want to delegate this Email Content creation work away from Facade layer and to make it more flexible.

Currently I am creating Registration email content inside `customerFacade` and some how I am not liking this way, since that means for each email, I need to create content in respective Facade.

What is best way to go or current approach is fine enough?

Comment: not worthy of an answer, but in instead of or maybe included within your email processor you could have an EmailTemplateFactory that uses several EmailTemplate strategies to contain each individual email/template.  This could be used with Stretch is answer below as the EmailRenderingService could be used to replace placeholders of the selected template from the factory.

Answer (score 0):

CustomerFacade? ServiceLayer? Is this Hybris?

Your instinct to move this away from your facade is correct. I would suggest an **EmailRenderingService**.

Pass a template and a Context object to a `render` method. You could use `Renderer` objects inside your service to render each different component in your email - like the text and images supplied from your CMS. These are contained in the template. The Context object contains the Customer and Order objects (etc) as I am sure is obvious.

But if this is hybris then look in the acceleratorservices extension where this is all done already. The three email examples you mention are exactly those provided out of the box. Named the same too, like all the classes in the question...

Comment: Well its not Hybris...and CustomerFacade is not Hybris specific though I know its there in Hybirs ;) and every ecommerce application have those email functionalities...anyways..you suggestion to have rendering service is worth trying :)